# Triggering Visual Basic Keydown events without a specific function

Tags: vba

I'm building on top of code that a previous developer has left me, and he left something that intrigued me quite a bit.

Basically on his menus, he has a TextBox to take in user input and a button next to it to submit the value of the TextBox (for example if the user wanted to select option 1, he would input 1 into the TextBox and click the button). However, the user could also press the Enter key while focusing the TextBox, and it would be treated as the submit button was clicked.

Now this is simple enough to do, but when I check the VB code behind the menu, there's no TextBox_Keydown(...) Handles TextBox.Keydown function anywhere, only the button click event. How is he doing this? He has several menus that are similar and I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered how he was doing it. He basically mapped the AcceptButton and CancelButton properties of the entire Windows Form to various button functions.

Answer (score 0):

A standard dialog box, if not told to act otherwise, enter does default command button and escape does cancel. In VB look at the properties Default for the command button.